# the set of compact operators on $H$ is nonunital

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

How to prove $K(H)$ is a nonunital ,where $K(H)$ is the set of compact operators on $H$,$H$ is a infinite dimensional Hilbert space? Can anyone give me some hints?Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Let $(x_n)_n$ be an orthonormal sequence in $H$. Prove that $\text{Id}(x_n) = x_n$ has no convergent subsequence.

Comment: One could add that a unit of $K(H)$ must be the identity operator (otherwise, it would still be possible that $K(H)$ has a unit, it just wouldn't be a unital subalgebra of $B(H)$ anymore). This follows by considering the (finite dimensional, hence compact) operators $S_{y,z}:x\mapsto (x,z)y$ for fixed $x,y\in H$: suppose $I$ is a unit, so that $(x,z)Iy=IS_{y,z}x=S_{y,z}x=(x,z)y$ for each $x,y,z\in H$. Choose eg $x=z\neq 0$ to conclude $Iy=y$, hence $I=\text{id}_H.

Answer (score 0):

For a projection $P\in B(H)$ to be compact, it has to be finite-rank. This is because its rank is $PH$, and the unit ball of a subspace will be compact if and only if said subspace is finite-dimensional.

Since $I$ is also a projection, it can only be compact when its image is finite-dimensional; that is, when $H$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: Do you mean P is a projection from H to a finite dimensional sapce spaned by basis elements?

Comment: Not entirely sure what your question is. Every projection projects onto a subspace. Every subspace of a Hilbert space is spanned by an orthonormal basis.